# Lazy scrolling jquery

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

So I am trying to implement lazy scrolling using jQuery by fetching items as an when required from the server.So this is how I am doing it.

- Detect the end of the page,make a server call with to retrieve N more items.
- Then clear the div load the items and set the scrollTop to the div top.
- When the user wants to go back read the previous listings again make a server call to retrieve back the items.

Here is the brief code.

```
if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0)
    {
        //end of the page,scrolling down retrieve N more listings
        doRequest("down");

    }

    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() == 0)
    {
       //top of the page,scrolling up
        doRequest("up");
    }
    });

function doRequest(scroll_dir)
{

    if(scroll_dir == "down")
    {
        if(jQuery("#detail").length)
            listing_id = jQuery("#detail input").last().val();
    }
    else if(scroll_dir == "up")
    {
        if(jQuery("#detail").length)
            listing_id = jQuery("#detail input").first().val();

    }
    jQuery.ajax({

    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: {params:params,start:listing_id,scroll_direction:scroll_dir}, 
           success: function(results)
           {

            if(results.length > 0)
            {
             jQuery('#detail').html("");
            }

           //load the results 
           //append to div,jQuery('#detail').append(data);
          //code skipped for brevity

        scrollTop = jQuery("#detail").offset().top;

        jQuery(window).scrollTop(scrollTop);

        } ,

         });
}
```

So I have a backend controller which takes the listing id with the scroll direction and returns the result.

So the downward scrolling is happening fine,but when I scroll upwards there is need to detect that point to make a server call to retreive N-1 to N-10 listings.But I am finding it difficult that point where I need to make the call as  `jQuery(window).scrollTop() == 0` doesnt work well for mobiles?

Any libraries which already do this?Any help would be helpful.Thanks.

Comment: There is a major flaw in  your lazy loading logic. starting from step 2, its a bad idea to clear the exisiting items on the current view and load new items as u may need to load them again when scrolled up like in your case. **Better solution:** you just append the new items to the exisiting list of items, so that you dont end up loading the same items again when scrolled up and also it improves your sites performance,since you load the items only once irrespective of no of times the page is scrolled up and down

Comment: @dreamweiver Thanks for the suggestion works fine now.

Comment: shall we close this question now ?

Comment: Yeah sure.Should I do it on my end?Sorry I am new.

Comment: yes i`ll post the above comments below as a answer, then you can just tick against it to close it. i`ll post it in a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a major flaw in your lazy loading logic.

**Issue with your approach :**

1. Your Step 1 is good but there is a major issue in step 2 and 3.
2. Starting from step 2, its a bad idea to clear the existing items on the current view or div and load new items as you may need to load them again when scrolled up like in your case.

**Better solution:**

- Append or Extend the new items to the exisiting list of items already loaded on the screen,so that you dont end up loading the same items again when
  scrolled up
- Also it improves your sites performance,since you
  load the items only once irrespective of no of times the page is
  scrolled up and down by the user.

*Note: There are a no of javascript/jquery plugin for lazy load functionality with more features which would take care of all your performance issue.**"Try not to Reinvent the wheel"***